# Can't access resources in application level

Tags: c#, xaml, resources

I have defined an Application.Resource in the App.xaml file of the project,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <resx:LocalizedStrings xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Workshop" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

and this is the LocalizedStrings class

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
    private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();

    public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
}
```

and in the Window level when I try to use this resource it fails

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

It throws and exception: Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '20' and line position '28'.

I need to mention that this is a desktop application written in c# and when I use the resource in window level it works fine. I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: May be try `My.Application.Resources....`